# iOS Dynamic Views inside a view controller

Tags: ios, swift

In our project we've a requirement like this.

Our webservice sends the neccesary data to create views in our applications
These datas are consist of multiple views with an order.
For example it can send a data like this

```
[{"ViewType":"Table","datas:":[....]},
 {"ViewType":"PieChart","datas":[...]},
 {"ViewType":"BarChart","datas":[...]}]
```

So we are going to show all these views in the same view controller , and when the user first open the view he/she will see the table then he'll scroll down and see the piechart etc...

Is something like that possible with any kind of design pattern in iOS
If it is how?

Thanks

Comment: you have to know all of the possible kind of the view first then create them beforehand in your app

Comment: Create tableView and design multiple cells, each cell will work as a single view that you want to show. For eg `TableCell`, `PieChartCell`, `BarChartCell` etc...

Comment: add a UIScrollView in the view controller and then keep adding the above view types dynamically using `addSubview` .

Comment: use ScrollView and keep adding might not as good as using UITableView with custom cell, it can reuse and waste less ram than keep adding new instance to UIScrollView

Comment: @tolgatanriverdi how did you solved this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use the table view or collection view. Each cell can have the single view, on the basis of count of the views, you can set the number of cells of the tableview or collection view. Disable the horizontal scrolling if required.